# HBase client does not work under JBoss AS 7.1

Tags: hadoop, jar, jboss, hbase, cloudera

i am having a JBoss application which needs to talk remotely with an HBase server. When using the simple console project the HBase client works perfectly but when deployed in the JBoss server looks like the server is not loading the class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.resources.UserProvider. 
Can anyone help with an workaround or with a fix ? ?

Your replies are much appreciated.

**Error message**
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/HFPlatformWeb]] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) StandardWrapper.Throwable: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.resources.UserProvider from ...

**List of jars**
commons-configuration-1.6.jar
commons-lang-2.5.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
guava-11.0.2.jar
hadoop-auth-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0.jar
hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0.jar
hadoop-core-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.4.0.jar
hadoop-hdfs-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0.jar
hbase.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh4.4.0.jar

Comment: Take under consideration that deploying HBase client on Jboss I not a good idea as currently I am facing a problem with that. HBase uses jersey and JBoss AS 7.1 uses  rest easy witch makes a conflict on deployment !

Answer (score 0):

- At least one clue should be in exception trace. It is strange you need `hdfs.web.resources` at all. Please look at your exception stack from one side and on cloudra JARs from another to see where this class 'lives'.
- Do you really have loaded `hadoop-hdfs`? As far as I remember it is not 'fixed' dependency but rather implementation of some mechanics to handle HDFS scheme.
- I'd recommend to upgrade Cloudera cluster to Cloudera 5 environment. Rather big step starting from HBase 0.96.x and Hadoop 2.3.x which is really serious advantage. For me another difference was YARN infrastructure as default MR handler. This seem not to fix your issue but if you don't do it now, you will get this upgrade complexity soon. It starts from HBase being split on sub-components rather than `hbase.jar` for CDH4. Dependencies look really different.

WARNING: Last point is just my recommendation based on my own experience if your cluster is yet in experimental phase.